# External jar dependency (migration to gradle 3.0)

Tags: android, gradle, migration, samsung-mobile-sdk

I've got some problems with setting dependencies to Samsung SDK and Slook libraries (Edge) after migration to gradle 3.0 plugin (3.0.0-beta6).

> compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

If I add dependency like above, it doesn't work for API <= 19

```
Could not find class 'com.samsung.android.sdk.look.Slook', referenced from method (...))
```

> compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

If I add dependency like this, it doesn't work for API > 19

```
"com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for com/samsung/android/sdk/look/Slook.class"
```

Is it my configuration problem or maybe in Samsung SDK?

Is there any way to make it work correctly? (In code or build.gradle?)

VERSIONS:

- Android Studio 3.0 beta 6.
- Gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta6.
- sdk-v1.0.0.jar
- slook_v1.4.0.jar